# iPhone dev - I have a bunch of addresses and want to plot them all in a MapView

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, geocoding

I've heard that there is no supported forward geocoding in corelocation. Can someone please guide me in the right direction to how I could figure this out? I've tried downloading a third party forward geocoding thing and I couldn't get it to work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the location data from [The Google Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) and point the results to the map.

Answer (score 0):

[Check validity of address with Geocoding on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863992/check-validity-of-address-with-geocoding-on-iphone)

Refer to this link. Once you get coordinates, you can add annotations.