# Check validity of address with Geocoding on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-maps, geolocation

I have an app which prompts the user to input an address. Is there a way to check whether or not the address is a valid address, either using Google's Maps or Places APIs or not? Any help would be appreciated. I know it's a vague question but I'm not really sure how to ask it any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fast way to kill 95% spam profiles was for my company to have a onboard list of us state names and zip codes. If zip code and state did not match, we peomted the user to check again.

Not foolproof at all, but if spammers are the problem, this might help.

Comment: What if not all your users are in the US as would be the case for most people in the world

Comment: Matti, zip codes exists well outside the US, most areas in EU has zip code, as well as china, japan, and russia. But as stated, the solution is not perfect, but could be an introductionary step to get the worst entries out of the way :)

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", 
                       [addressField.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; // addressField is where you enter your address.
NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

if([listItems count] >= 4 && [[listItems objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
    latitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
    longitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
```

If address exists you will get coordinates in latitude and longitude. Hope this helps.